# Calculating percent of 'group' total without creating new pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new series to a dataframe that calculates the percent of group total. Thing is, I don't want a new dataframe. Here is my sample data:

df:

[image]

my desired output would be:

[image]

Any ideas, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following BigBen's suggestion, you can calculate this as:

```
df['Percent total of male'] = df.groupby('Gender')['Amount'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

Otherwise, in a more step-by-step approach you can also try:

```
df['Percent total of male'] = np.where(df['Gender'] == 'Male',df['Amount'] / df[df['Gender'] =='Male']['Amount'].sum(),df['Amount'] / df[df['Gender']!='Male']['Amount'].sum()
```

In which `df['Amount'].sum()` will be a scalar, and the division will calculate each rows value as % of total.

Comment: Right on. That was more simple than I thought with the lambda function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also surprised, I ran 1000 iterations on a 500k rows dataframe and both np.where() and groupby-transform had a very similar average execution time. I was expecting groupby-transform to be slower